# Kotlin Scope functions not working in Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Not able to use kotlin scope functions in android studio, showing unresolved reference.
Studio Version : Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 patch 4

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
def HILT_VERSION ="2.38.1"
def NAV_VERSION = "2.3.5"
def RETROFIT_VERSION = "2.9.0"
def OKHTTP_VERSION = "4.9.0"

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ezcart"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$HILT_VERSION"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$HILT_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$NAV_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$NAV_VERSION"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    // Retrofit with Gson Converter
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OKHTTP_VERSION"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$OKHTTP_VERSION"

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To use **Kotlin** functions, including **Scope functions**, add dependency:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

This is **[Kotlin Standard Library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/)**, which provides living essentials for everyday work with **Kotlin**. These include:

- Higher-order functions implementing idiomatic patterns (let, apply, use, synchronized, etc).
- Extension functions providing querying operations for collections (eager) and sequences (lazy).
- Various utilities for working with strings and char sequences.
- Extensions for JDK classes making it convenient to work with files, IO, and threading.

Comment: I have already added that you can see it in the question itself

Comment: You added `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`, but `kotlin-stdlib` is required. Please check.

Comment: I did not add this.. there was a mismatch with versions used in project and app gradle files.Changing that fixed the issue.